# Transliterate Thai to Latin using RTGS in ICU Project

Tags: java, icu, latin, thai

I am using the ICU Project to perform some transliterations, but I am finding some issues while transliterating from Thai to Latin. I would need to use the RTGS [(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Thai_General_System_of_Transcription)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Thai_General_System_of_Transcription) standard, but it seems as it is not implemented in ICU Project. 
I trully appreciate any help regarding how to add RTGS to ICU Project, or at least any Project developed in Java.

Thanks in advance